# Detect if facebook comments is loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I detect with jQuery if facebook comments iframe has loaded. I am lazy loading the comments.

I tried the following but it didn't work.

```
 $('<iframe/>').on("load", function(){
     alert('the iframe is done loading');
 }).appendTo('body');
```

Thanks.

Comment: The `.on` is misspelt. Closing as typo. Also, there's no comma after `'load'`.

Comment: thanks I updated that.

Answer (score 1):

When you load Facebook JS SDK, you need to subscribe to the `xfbml.render` event:

```
FB.Event.subscribe('xfbml.render', function() {
     alert('the iframe is done loading');
});
```